# Spring Boot 2 - availableProcessors() returning 1 always

Tags: spring-boot, cpu-cores, processors

Java 8, Spring Boot 2. 
I was testing performance using multiple threads and CompletableFuture when I realized that only 1 core in choking and rest of them are basically not doing much work.
[high load on only 1 core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Mje.png)

Some load on other cores is probably caused by other processes running on the machine. 
I tried to figure out what is the issue and than realized that

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

is always returning 1 in runtime. It doesn't matter if I started multiple threads or not, number is always 1 (should be 8). 
Then I created simple Unit test class and run availableProcessors() code and got 8. Cleary, something connected to Spring context is making runtime not to see all available cores. 
Help?

Comment: Are you sure you are not running this within some VM or container that limits the number of CPU available to the process?

Comment: VM that limits - for sure No. Container - not sure, I'm guessing that Spring container is doing that limiting and not sure why. That is main issue

Comment: tomcat also doesn't have any settings connected to this topic or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was not connected to Hibernate, Spring or any other container. We have jni4net Bridge registering DLL file (3rd party library) during startup. When first Service class from the DLL was instantiated we got reduction from 8 to 1 core... Obviously something to do with dll or the bridge. Since that is the issue of completely other kind I think thats enough for this post.